# How can I have a staging site for my Azure web app with its own database?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, continuous-deployment, azure-sql-database, azure-deployment-slots

I have an MVC website that is connected to an azure web app and has continuous deployment to a staging site set up. It works great! After I check in, the successful build is automatically deployed to the staging slot of my webapp. After I verify that staging looks good, I can swap the two slots to make prod into stage and vice versa.

Recently I decided that I wanted the production and staging slots to connect to distinct databases so that I can enter test data into the staging site without cluttering the prod database.

I naively though I could do this by editing the connection strings in the configuration for the staging site to point to a new database. It seemed to work, but the next time I swapped configurations after a deploy, I realized that the connection strings get swapped in the process. This is not what I was aiming for.

Does anyone know how I can have the two deployment slots point to different databases and to maintain those connections after the swap? Is there another way I should be thinking of this?

Answer (score 5):

Azure provides the answer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/#configuration-for-deployment-slots). I copy-edited their text below.

> Some configuration elements will follow the content across a swap (not
>   slot specific) while other configuration elements will stay in the
>   same slot after a swap (slot specific).
>
> Luckily, connection strings can be configured to stick to a slot. To
>   configure a connection string to stick to a slot (not swapped), access
>   the **Application Settings** blade for a specific slot, then select
>   the **Slot Setting** box for the configuration elements that should
>   stick the slot.
>
> [image]